# What is the complexity of List.nth in OCaml? Can we find the nth element in OCaml in O(1)?

Tags: list, ocaml, selection, time-complexity

I found the manual of OCaml List module did not say how the List.nth does. Does it cost O(1) or O(n) like some plain recursive implementation. If List.nth is O(n), can we write a function to find the nth element in O(1) time in OCaml?

Answer (score 9):

Standard lists are "singly-linked", so it will always be O(n).

Comment: So what type we should use if I want to find nth element in O(1)?

Comment: @Indicator Arrays. That said, you might first want to think about whether you really need random access for your use case.

Comment: Does random access bring extra cost for a functional programming language?

Comment: @Indicator array is the same in OCaml as any other language, so, no.

Comment: @Indicator No, but it makes your code less functional (that is arrays do (since they are mutable, random access by itself does not). Also most common things can be done without random accesses when done in a functional style. If you really need random access, then by all means use arrays, but if you find yourself needing it all the time, you might not be writing very functional code.

Comment: Lists can be extended (at the beginning) in O(1) space and time, arrays would be O(n) in both. If you construct the container incrementally (inductively), as you often do in functional programming, it sums up as O(n) for lists, but will become O(n^2) for normal arrays. Related, lists allow sharing (in space) between different vesions/extensions, where arrays do not.

Answer (score 3):

It is **O(n)**.

And as long as it is a `standard linked-list`, you can't find the nth element in O(1) in any language.

Answer (score 1):

1) If we look at the implementation of List.nth in https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/blob/master/lib/core_list.ml (Lines 193 to 200) we see that it calls a tail recursive function that uses the cons (::) operator to repeatedly extract the head element. Therefore, we can be sure that it is indeed O(n).

2) If the lists that we were working with were big we could convert them into arrays using to_array ( val to_array : 'a t -> 'a array ) and use these arrays for more efficient lookups. But this approach works only in very simple cases where the we build the entire list first and then perform the lookups. I'd like to think of these array as indexes for the lists; and like in relational db implementations we would have to update the indexes when the base data changes.